# Why is there a white border on the get started button

Tags: html, css, button

I just started learning to code today and I have come across this problem.
I get this white border around my get started button and I can't figure out why.
When I change the margin-top, it gets smaller, but the space between the text above it gets smaller as well, witch I do not want. Thanks for the help in advance. (I don't know if the layout of this question is done right, so any tips on doing that would also be helpful).

[image]

```css
.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1>NEXT GENERATION</h1>
      <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
      <P>See what make us different.</P>
      <button><div class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></div></button>
    </div>
    <div class="main__img--container"><img src="images/pic1.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible it is coming from the background image?

Comment: `button` should not contain links. It's invalid HTML. Buttons **do** something, links **go** somewhere.

Comment: ...so apply your button styling to an anchor element instead, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 2px default border on the button

```css
.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.main {
  padding: 1em;
}

button {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__container">
    <div class="main__content">
      <h1>NEXT GENERATION</h1>
      <h2>TECHNOLOGY</h2>
      <P>See what make us different.</P>
      <button><div class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></div></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: im sorry. i am vey new at this. What do i write where? i wrote the margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; under the .main__btn, but it didn't work. thanks for the help btw

Comment: Note the border being removed from the button

Comment: place your div before the button